# How can I check between two pages if they are equal?

Tags: c#, selenium

I copied a share link , now I need to know if he really copied all the 
details including the small details.
How can I check between two pages if they are equal?

I tried to do something like that, it could work?

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("my-url");

IWebElement sourcePage = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body"));

driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("share-link")).Click();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Clipboard.GetText());

IWebElement copiedPage = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")); 

// The test
if (copiedPage.Equals(sourcePage))
{
    // The pages are equal
}
else
{ 
    // Pages not equal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML Pages are usually just really long, multiline strings. Just load both into memory and comapre them. But do be warned that strings tend to evaluate not equal when you do not expect it, and the longer it is the more likely false/unexpected negatives become.

You may want to actually find the lines that are different. This would be a very different question, but can be done by turning the pages into a `string[]` or `List<Strings>`, and then comapre each element/line.

If you do this kind of comparision a lot, it can be helpfull to compute a hash value for both sides ahead of time. Just looking at the hash value, you can quickly spot if the pages are different. If the hash value are indentical, you still do a string wise comparision as has colissions can happen.